# filter function from tidyverse and as.numeric()

Tags: r, tidyverse

I had to force my data frame into character and pivot to get the final outpu I have. I am trying to do the following 3 tasks.

1. all the location of the cells that can't be turned into numeric using `as.numeric()`
2. filter rows where all the specific columns that end with "_chart" are NA.
3. filter rows where Ref value doesn't match with any of _chart columns

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
compared <- structure(list(ID = c("51-07518", "51-07518", "51-07518", "51-07518", 
"51-07518", "51-07518"), name = c("SC5pos", "SC7pos", "SC1", 
"SC4neg", "SC6pos", "Not found"), Ref = c("1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1"), A_chart = c("R2", NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    A2_chart = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    "1", "0", NA_character_), B_chart = c(NA_character_, 
    "0", NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), D_chart = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    "1", NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 7
>   ID       name      Ref   A_chart A2_chart B_chart D_chart
>   <chr>    <chr>     <chr> <chr>    <chr>             <chr>   <chr>  
> 1 51-07518 SC5pos    1     R2       NA                NA      NA     
> 2 51-07518 SC7pos    1     NA       NA                0       NA     
> 3 51-07518 SC1       1     NA       NA                NA      1      
> 4 51-07518 SC4neg    1     NA       1                 NA      NA     
> 5 51-07518 SC6pos    1     NA       0                 NA      NA     
> 6 51-07518 Not found 1     NA       NA                NA      NA
> ```

I read the forums and commands from dplyr and thought `filter_at`? Something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
filter_at(compared, vars(ends_with("chart")), all_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

Comment: What is your expected output? `filter_at(compared, vars(ends_with("chart")), all_vars(is.na(.)))` does give you rows with all `NA` right ?

Comment: I meant to do !is.na(.) I am trying to exclude the rows where *_chart columns are NA. Just edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `any_vars` and combine multiple conditions together.

```
dplyr::filter_at(compared, vars(ends_with("chart")), any_vars(!is.na(.) & . != Ref))

# A tibble: 3 x 7
#   ID       name  Ref   A_chart A2_chart B_chart D_chart
#  <chr>    <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   <chr>  
#1 51-07518 SC5pos 1     R2      NA       NA      NA     
#2 51-07518 SC7pos 1     NA      NA       0       NA     
#3 51-07518 SC6pos 1     NA      0        NA      NA
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to pipe in  `dplyr::filter_at(compared, vars(ends_with("charts")), any_vars(!is.na(.))) %>% filter(vars(ends_with("charts")), any_vars!=Ref)` Second part doesnt work

Comment: @user171558 You mean `df %>%
  filter_at(vars(ends_with("chart")), any_vars(!is.na(.))) %>%
  filter_at(vars(ends_with("chart")), any_vars(. != Ref))` ?

Comment: `dims [product 181907] do not match the length of object [204196]` Could this be due to Ref having NA values?

Comment: Can you try the updated version from the answer? It seems to work on the sample data at least.

Comment: Works! I mislabeled a column. Question 3, (Last one I promise). Is there a way to find out which values can't be turned into numeric? ie. compared[1,"A_chart"]

Comment: Do you want to convert columns to numeric ? The best way is to use `type.convert` which will automatically convert columns to it's respective type. `dplyr::filter_at(compared, vars(ends_with("chart")), any_vars(!is.na(.) & . != Ref)) %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)` Or remove `as.is = TRUE` if you need character columns as factors.